# conda environment and channels

Tags: python, conda

According to the [documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment), if I use

```
 conda env export > file.yml
```

I am able to share the environment with others. For better cross-platform compatibility, a better way would be:

```
conda env export --from-history > file.yml
```

listing only the packages explicitly requested (and not their associated dependencies).

That is what I did, I created a requirement yml file with the second command. Here it is:

```
name: torch
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - humanize
  - nltk
  - pandas
  - lxml
  - numpy
  - bs4
  - fire
  - neptune-client
  - tqdm
  - pyyaml
  - torchaudio
  - pytorch
  - cudatoolkit=11.3
  - torchvision
```

Among those packages, some were installed from the channel `conda-forge`: channels seem to be lost in the yaml file.

Indeed, if I try and use that file for cloning the environment (same machine):

```
conda env create -n torch2 --file=file.yml
```

I get an error for the packages installed from `conda-forge` (I explicitly installed from conda-forge only neptune-client and fire):

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - torchaudio
  - neptune-client
  - fire
```

However, it seems that channels should be included in the yml. For example, [on this github issue page](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2350) I read:

```
Currently, conda env export does include channels information.
```

that closes the issue.

What am I missing?

NOTE: pytorch was installed with

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch
```

from the official web page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I missing?

**The docs are wrong** - or  misleading (at best) when it is [communicated](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#exporting-an-environment-file-across-platforms) that `conda env export --from-history` exports the channels that packages are installed from, or even any channels at all. This is not the behavior you get, nor is it what I get myself:

```sh
$ conda env export | head -n 8
name: smithy
channels:
- bioconda
- conda-forge
- defaults
dependencies:
- _libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
- _openmp_mutex=4.5=1_gnu
$ conda env export --from-history | head -n 8
name: smithy
channels:
- defaults
dependencies:
- mamba
- constructor
- cookiecutter
- conda-build
```

Note that `conda env export` *does* include channel information, but in a highly-pinned way that's almost guaranteed to not work across platforms. So that's not going to work for your use case. I'm not sure if this is a bug or an oversight, but it's clearly not producing the desired result for the user.

Now to offer a (opinionated) recommendation on how to proceed: your best bet is to semi-manually curate an environment YAML file yourself and use that as a single source of truth. It looks like you can use your `name: torch ...` file a s a starting point, adding in the channels and maybe some other details as you go. Don't forget you can tie an individual package to a channel with the `channel::package` syntax a la

```
name: torch
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
  - torch 
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
<SNIP>
  - pytorch::torchaudio
  - pytorch::pytorch
  - pytorch::cudatoolkit=11.3
  - pytorch::torchvision
```

Comment: Note `conda env export` picks up channels from the *configuration*, not the packages. This means that (1) if one never adds a channel to configuration (`conda config --add channel <channel>`), then it will not show up; (2) running `conda env export -n <env_name>` is sensitive to the active environment. Both of these are bad things that Conda should address (consider opening a new issue or two).

Comment: Also, this is not the best example of channel ordering in a YAML. Better practice would be priority of `pytorch > conda-forge > defaults`. When people want Pytorch, that should be highest priority, and if Conda Forge is at all needed, it should almost always take precedence over **defaults**. Otherwise, one risks encountering [channel mixing issues](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels).